# Ways to quickly split big table into shards

Tags: mysql, innodb, partitioning, sharding

Assume I've a big MySQL InnoDB table (100Gb) and want to split these data between shards. The tables looks like this `Post(id: int, user_id: int, body: text, ...)`. Table is heavily indexed. Server is hosted on AWS and uses EBS disks.

Splitting should be performed based on `user_id` key. Eg. user's posts with id 1..100  should be stored on shard1, user's posts with id 101..200 should be stored on shard2 and so on.

I've tried `INSERT .. SELECT`, but estimation indicated, that this would take up to 5 days.

So, are there any ideas on how to spit the data in reasonable time?

Answer (score 0):

Copy your table structure while removing all the INDEX definitions and the use INSERT-SELECT to fill them. Once you are done, use a single ALTER TABLE statement to add the necessary indexes.

Comment: With AWS EBS disks it takes weeks :( Dropping indexes doesn't help very much

Comment: Have you tried LOAD DATA INFILE? This is a lot faster for restoring tables http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140879/mysql-select-into-outfile-export-options/9143021 .

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use stored procedure to read each record and copy over to different shards.

Comment: Would this be faster than using an INSERT/SELECT? If so, please post some sample-code to support your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The bottleneck is the write speed of your disk subsystem.

Tricks to speed up imports:

MyISAM is not transactional, so much faster in single threaded inserts. Try to load into MyISAM, then ALTER the table to INNODB
Use ALTER TABLE .. DISABLE KEYS to avoid index updates line by line (MyISAM only)
Set bulk_insert_buffer_size above your insert size (MyISAM only)
Set unique_checks = 0 so that unique constraints are not checked.

for further tuning detals please see following:
[MYSQL Huge SQL Files Insertion | MyISAM speed suddenly slow down for Insertions (strange issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19004117/mysql-huge-sql-files-insertion-myisam-speed-suddenly-slow-down-for-insertions?lq=1)

Note: If the original table have foreign key constraints, using MyISAM as an intermediate format is a bad idea.