# MySQL SELECT INTO OUTFILE Export options

Tags: mysql, into-outfile

Does anyone know where can I find the documentation for all the export options of the SELECT ... OUTFILE statement of MySQL? 
I have noticed in multiple questions parameters such as

```
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY delimiter
FIELDS ESCAPED BY delimiter
FIELDS TERMINATED BY delimiter
```

but I haven't managed to find the complete list of parameters yet.
Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the official [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html).

You might want to take a look at [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) too, as it seems the syntax from [FIELDS] and [LINES] is taken from the "load data infile"

Comment: Really useful links. For some strange matter they wouldn't come up in my search. I didn't think of looking in the LOAD DATA INFILE either. Great answer, thanks!

Comment: same as wisefish. didn't come up in my search and I did not think to look at the docs for load data infile